# Getting the value of a select, with onchange and add row id number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi guys I'm having a hard time with this one please help me.

So I have an add row function where I can add dynamic rows to the form. My plan is to get the value of the **Particulars** with onchange event. So when you change the particular if will get the current value of the selected Particulars specifically on the selected row only.

The form looks like this:[image]

So to test this out I'm trying to put the value in alert messages.

So this is the one I've done so far, I don't know if I'm making this correctly.

**This is my html code**.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="addSubPaymentTable">
<thead>
 <tr>
 <th >Particulars</th>
 <th style="width:10%;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="addPaymentRow()">Add Row</button></th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <?php $arrayNumber = 0; for($x = 1; $x < 2; $x++) { ?>
  <tr id="row<?php echo $x; ?>" class="<?php echo $arrayNumber; ?>">      

  <td class="form-group">

  <select class="form-control particulars" name="subparticulars[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="subparticulars<?php echo $x; ?>" 
onchange="specificBalance('<?php echo $x; ?>')" />  //AS YOU CAN SEE I HAVE AN ONCHANGE EVENT HERE
  <option value="">Select Particulars</option>
  <?php foreach ($particularsData as $particulars)
  {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $particulars['feetype_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $particulars['feetype_name']; ?> </option>

  <?php 
  } 
  ?>
  </select>    

 <?php $arrayNumber++; } // /.foreach?>
</tbody>
```

So this is the function for the onchange event of Specific Balance

**Javascript**

```
// Get Specific Balance
function specificBalance(row = null)
{
var particular = $(this).val();

alert('Testing value is' +particular );
}
```

Please help me to get the value of the Particular, that is different in every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
  <select class="form-control particulars" name="subparticulars[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="subparticulars<?php echo $x; ?>"
```

onchange="specificBalance('')" />

with

```
  <select class="form-control particulars" name="subparticulars[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="subparticulars<?php echo $x; ?>"
```

onchange="specificBalance(this)" />

and in the jquery function use this

```
function specificBalance(row = null)
{
    var particular = $(row).val();

    alert('Testing value is' +particular );
}
```

Comment: Hi I have other question, what if I want it to pass the value to another input, within the same row

Comment: then you have to call the function for that input event

Answer (score 1):

Use this.value in onchange() function for select tag in HTML

```
 <select class="form-control particulars" name="subparticulars[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="subparticulars<?php echo $x; ?>" 
    onchange="specificBalance(this.value)" />  //AS YOU CAN SEE I HAVE AN ONCHANGE EVENT HERE
      <option value="">Select Particulars</option>
      <?php foreach ($particularsData as $particulars)
      {
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $particulars['feetype_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $particulars['feetype_name']; ?> </option>

      <?php 
      } 
      ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: And how to pass the value of it in the alert messages? This is for the purpose that I want to pass that value in an ajax or a controller to get a specific value of the balance.

Comment: then it will find and go to specificBalance() function in your JavaScript code from there you can sen that value to ajax if you have written that function on that page or any js file that you have called